# Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly python

Tags: python, string, list

```
elif used_prefix and cmd == "xp":
            if self.getAccess(user) >= 1:
                f = open("users/" + user.name.lower() + ".txt", 'r')
                word = f.readline().split("X Points = ")
                if word == "0":
                        room.message("You have no X Points")
                else:
                    room.message("You Have " + word + " X Points")
                f.close()
            else:
                room.message("You are not whitelisted " + user.name.capitalize())
```

When I try to use XP it shows `Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly` as the error in the console. I'm using python 3.3.

Comment: Can you show what does the file looks like?

Comment: its just X points = 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need

```
word = f.readline().split("X Points = ")[1].strip()
```

as you are splitting, it will return the list of items split as a list. You need to take the  element corresponding to the actual value

**Example**

```
data = "X Points = 10"
print data.split("X Points = ")
```

**Output**

```
['', '10']
```

So, we need to get the second element. Thats why we use `[1]`

Comment: thanks but it does not say you have no xpoints when its 0 and it doesnt show the value if there is it only you have  X Points help?

The text in file is X Points = 0

Comment: @user3065432 Could you please explain the previous comment also in the question?

Comment: If X Points = 0 i want it to send You have no X Points and if it greater than 0 i want it to send eg. You Have 5 X Points

Comment: @user3065432 please Check my updated answer, you may have to `strip` the white space characters

Comment: thanks and can u help with 1 more thing 
How can i split two texts example: /give user.name 99
Hpw can i split it so user.name and 99 can be used seperately

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that split returns a list, not a string.

```
if self.getAccess(user) >= 1:
    with open("users/{}.txt".format(user.name.lower()), 'r') as f:
         word = f.readline().split("X Points = ")[1]
    if word == "0":
         room.message("You have no X Points")
    else:
         room.message("You Have {} X Points".format(word))
else:
    room.message("You are not whitelisted {}".format(user.name.capitalize()))
```

Comment: How can i split two texts
example 
/give user.name 99
it can use the values user.name and the 99 seperately